# Telescope error when running composer --no-dev

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

When I want to deploying my app to production. I simply run

> composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

Which will result an error.

> In TelescopeServiceProvider.php line 10:
> Class 'Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider' not
> found
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the
> post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: In composer.json, do you put "laravel/telescope" in require or require-dev section?

Comment: @QuynhXuanNguyen Yes I have put "laravel/telescope" in compser.json on require-dev section

Comment: just run `composer install`

Comment: @KamleshPaul but i don't want the telescope installed on production

Comment: In config/app.php, does TelescopeServiceProvider exists inside 'providers' key?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Remove `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class` from `config/app.php` because all providers inside config/app.php is automatically loaded. But in your production environment, `laravel/telescope` isn't installed that means `Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider` is undefined and `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider` can not extend an undefined class.
2. Register `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class` manually inside `app/Providers/AppServiceProviders.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if (class_exists(TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider::class)) {
            $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: this feels like something telescope should have taken care of itself